# Export Zoo Members channel data

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, export

Does anyone know of an easy way to export the Zoo members data.

I am having a play with ajw_export but I have a feeling it isn't going to quite do what I need.

This is what I need from the export

```
Name         [standard member data]  
Email        [standard member data]

Business     [zoo member data - checkbox]   
Education    [zoo member data - checkbox]    
Fund         [zoo member data - checkbox]   
Newsletter   [zoo member data - checkbox]
```

With ajw.export I've got the following query

```
{exp:ajw_export 
  sql="SELECT member_id, screen_name, email FROM exp_members" 
  format="csv" 
  delimter=":"
}
```

This is fine, returns the id/name/email address, but the zoo members data isn't stored in the members table.  So I need to get field_id_55, field_id_56, field_id_115 and field_id_118 from channel_data.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at the database of one of my sites running Zoo Visitor.  You're going to have to pull and link data from exp_members (to get the member ID), exp_channel_titles (to link the member ID with the author ID), and exp_channel_data (to get the rest of the data you want)

**Please note that i'm not a database expert!**

That said, try something like this:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.screen_name, m.email, d.field_id_55, d.field_id_56, d.field_id_115, d.field_id_118
FROM exp_members m, exp_channel_titles t, exp_channel_data d
where m.member_id = t.author_id and t.entry_id = d.entry_id
```

Comment: seems to do the job... nice one

Comment: Great!  And thanks for the lead on the AJW Export.  It might just come in handy for a project I've got coming up!